# How to add a logo path to my company table in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, image, forms, codeigniter, upload

I have an form for adding companies to my database. I've added a field called Logo. I want to use this field so the user can upload an Logo for their company. I am using the Codeigniter upload class in my form.

My company table looks like this:

```
Companies
---------
id
companyname
address
postalcode
country
email
website
logo
```

My form looks liek this:

```
<tr>
<td><?= form_label('Bedrijfsnaam:');?></td>
<td><?= form_input('Bedrijfsnaam');?><small> (Spaties niet toegestaan)</small></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><?= form_label('Adres:');?></td>
<td><?= form_input('Adres');?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><?= form_label('Postcode:');?></td>
<td><?= form_input('Postcode');?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><?= form_label('Plaats:');?></td>
<td><?= form_input('Plaats');?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><?= form_label('Telefoonnummer:');?></td>
<td><?= form_input('Telefoonnummer');?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><?= form_label('Website:');?></td>
<td><?= form_input('Website');?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><?= form_label('Email:');?></td>
<td><?= form_input('Email');?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><?= form_label('Profiel:');?></td>
<td><?= form_textarea('Profiel');?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><?= form_label('Categorieen:'); ?></td>
<td><?= form_dropdown('categorieen', $opties); ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><?= form_label('Logo:'); ?></td>
<td><input type="file" name="logo" size="20" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><?= form_submit('submit', 'Opslaan');?> <?= form_reset('reset', 'Reset');?></td>
</tr>
```

My model looks like this:

```
    $data1 = array( 
        'Bedrijfsnaam' => $this->input->post('Bedrijfsnaam'), 
        'Postcode' => $this->input->post('Postcode'), 
        'Plaats' => $this->input->post('Plaats'), 
        'Telefoonnummer' => $this->input->post('Telefoonnummer'), 
        'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'), 
        'Website' => $this->input->post('Website'), 
        'Profiel' => $this->input->post('Profiel'), 
        'Adres' => $this->input->post('Adres'), 
        'logo' => $this->input->post('logo') 
    ); 
    $this->db->insert('bedrijven',$data1);
```

I know this won't work but I can't figure out how to do this.

I have another uploadform but that's only for uploading images, not for the logo.

What's the best way to do this using the upload class?

---

EDIT:

I get an empty field when I add a new company.

My controller:

```
    function addbedrijven()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['max_width']  = '';
        $config['max_height']  = '';
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload('logo')){

        $logo_image_data = $this->upload->data();

        }
        $this->members_model->addbedrijf();
        redirect('members/index');
    }
```

My Model:

```
    function addbedrijf() 
    { 
        $logo_image_data = $this->upload->data();

        $data1 = array( 
            'Bedrijfsnaam' => $this->input->post('Bedrijfsnaam'), 
            'Postcode' => $this->input->post('Postcode'), 
            'Plaats' => $this->input->post('Plaats'), 
            'Telefoonnummer' => $this->input->post('Telefoonnummer'), 
            'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'), 
            'Website' => $this->input->post('Website'), 
            'Profiel' => $this->input->post('Profiel'), 
            'Adres' => $this->input->post('Adres'), 
            'logo' => $logo_image_data['full_path'] 
        ); 
        $this->db->insert('bedrijven',$data1); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `codeigniter` `upload` class within the same form

```
      $config_logo_image = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
        'upload_path' => UPLOAD_PATH,
        'max_size' => 2000,
        );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config_logo_image );                    
    if($this->upload->do_upload('logo_image')){

    $logo_image_data = $this->upload->data();

    }
```

And through this data in the your `$data` array

```
    $data1 = array( 
    'Bedrijfsnaam' => $this->input->post('Bedrijfsnaam'), 
    'Postcode' => $this->input->post('Postcode'), 
    'Plaats' => $this->input->post('Plaats'), 
    'Telefoonnummer' => $this->input->post('Telefoonnummer'), 
    'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'), 
    'Website' => $this->input->post('Website'), 
    'Profiel' => $this->input->post('Profiel'), 
    'Adres' => $this->input->post('Adres'), 
    'logo' => $logo_image_data ['full_path']  // it is full path of image 
); 
$this->db->insert('bedrijven',$data1);
```

`'logo' =>$logo_image_data ['file_name'] //only file name`

Hope it makes sense

Comment: I can't get it to work. I will update my question with the code i have so far.

Comment: see `enctype` of form is it `multipart` ?? and in your controller `var_dump($_FILES)` and see are you getting image info in `$_FILES`

Comment: My form is multipart. I will try var_dump

Comment: hm i see this array(1) { ["logo"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(14) "logo-SIBON.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpad8GPT" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(33197) } } no full_path or file_path there :o what could be the problem?

Comment: full_path and file path will return by `$this->upload->data();` upload library have you load this or it exists ??? in your directory

Comment: I've loaded the upload lib yes.

Comment: in upload path `$config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';` provide the exact root path why `./` ??

Comment: because of codeigniter. my root 'www/httpdocs' so root /assets/uploads/

Comment: Try to do it without using `./` like `$config['upload_path'] = 'assets/uploads/';`

Comment: that does not work. As I mentioned in my question i have another uploadform for other images. and those work with the `./`.

Comment: i got it working. i had an typo in my model. i fixed it with your code thanks.